# Double slit experiment with changes

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment

Couldn't find information about this anywhere. Maybe someone can tell me where I might find it.

What happens when the approach angle of the particle/light beam is changed as opposed to directly in front/perpendicular to the slits?

Also, what would happen if the barrier were composed of two sheets side by side, each with one slit, but the sheets are spaced so one is further away from the light source? Would the result still be the same interference?

Comment: Given that electron diffraction works just fine, I'm not sure what line of reasoning you are trying to follow.

Answer (score 3):

Yes if your incident beam comes in at an angle, you will still get interference: the "central peak" will simply be shifted (along the path of the incident beam).

[image]

In the above diagram, the red line represents the direction of the incident beam, and the grey dashed line the "normal incidence" direction. So in the second image, the diffraction pattern is shifted (but the spacing is unchanged; all that really happened is that you added a constant phase difference between the two slits, when compared to normal incidence).

If the two slits are (slightly) staggered (along the direction of the incident beam), it has no impact on the position or spacing of the fringes. This stops being true when the stagger is so great that the aperture starts to block the beam from the other slit.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I find it interesting that not only that events at different times can be in superposition, but also that the possibility of the particle going through both slits can also be separated by time (as they are spaced apart).